# How to pause a slideshow by hovering over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, I have the slideshow working but I don't know how to tell if the mouse if hovering the image.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var hovering = false;
    $('#slideshow').hover(function () {   //not sure if #slideshow is the right thing to put here
        hovering = true;
    }, function () {
        hovering = false;
        slideShow();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        slideShow();
    });
    function slideShow() {
        if(!hovering) {
            var showing = $('#slideshow .show');
            var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');
            var timer;
            showing.fadeOut(500, function() { next.fadeIn(200).addClass('show'); }).removeClass('show');
            setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img class="show" src="../images/food/chicken_quesa.jpg">
    <img src="../images/food/beet_salad.jpg">
    <img src="../images/food/pasta_display.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timer;

    $("#slideshow div").hide();

    $("#slideshow")
        // when mouse enters, clear the timer if it has been set
        .mouseenter(function() {
            if (timer) { clearInterval(timer) }
        })
        // when mouse goes out, start the slideshow
        .mouseleave(function() {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                $("#slideshow > div:first")
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo("#slideshow");
            }, 3000);
        })
        // trigger mouseleave for initial slideshow starting
        .mouseleave();

});​
```

Comment: The pictures dont even appear

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter and mouseleave` for it:

```
$('#slideshow').mouseenter(function () {
    hovering = true;
}).mouseleave(function () {
    hovering = false;
    slideShow();
});
```

Read docs [Mouse Enter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and  [Mouse Leave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)